# How to write a If, Else if in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I need to convert the following C code to its equivalent in Assembly. I've only taken a few classes on assembly and don't really have a grasp of the language yet.

```
int x = 45
int y = 27
while (x != y) {
   if (x > y)
      x = x - y;
   else if (y > x)
      y = y - x;
}  
return x;  // Sends exit code containing GCD
```

I have written what i believe to work and am about to use a debugger to find inevitable flaws but wanted to ask if i am headed in the right direction with the if else statement.

```
    .global _start
    _start

    mov R1, #45  @R1 = 45
    mov R2, #27  @R2 = 27

    loopTop:
    cmp R1, R2
    beq allDone
    bge R1,R2
    sub R1,R1,R0
    bge R2,R1
    sub R2,R2,R1
    b loopTop


    allDone:
    SWI R1
```

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: I assume this is ARM?  seems like a mixture of arm and mips.  Please tag and indicate the instruction set.

Comment: you did download the documentation on the instruction set before attempting to write any code yes?

Comment: Yes i have. Im also referring to it as i write but am just looking for outside opinion as well.

Comment: bge R2,R1  I am not familiar with this syntax, what does it do?

Comment: Error: garbage following instruction -- `bge r1,r2'

Comment: `bge` means branch if greater, but the syntax is wrong it should be `bge <label>`.

Comment: From my understanding it is Branch if greater than or equal too.

Comment: if/when you look at the arm docs you see that b(ge) has no register operands.  just a pc-relative offset.

Comment: (I knew the answer when I asked it)

Comment: @CluelessCollegeStuden my mistake it is branch if greater and equal

Comment: `mov r0, #9` `bx lr` 

Comment: is this ARM or thumb?  you can use the condition field on all arm instructions for example SUBGE

Comment: yes an optimizing compiler is going to just compute the answer unless you put the code in a function and feed it variables.  you can easily compile this and disassemble or compile to asm and see what the compiler does then try to understand that

Comment: on a more serious note this tool is godsent (or Godbolt sent ) for inspecting / sharpening your assembly skills https://godbolt.org/z/CmF4vW

Comment: also examine the sub instructions to see if/when they modify the flags, do you need to repeat the compare for each conditional branch as would be the norm for many other instruction sets?

Comment: Thank you all! Sounds like i need to use the pc-relative instead of the register operands

Comment: Use a debugger and/or google for similar questions *first* before you ask the world's experts to spend their time on your homework, please.

Comment: there is no register operand for a conditional branch, you need to look at the instruction set documentation.

Comment: but other than the beq you dont need any conditional branches.  if this is arm and not thumb

Comment: the armv5 architectural reference manual is the better one to start with for thumb/arm the latter ones are not laid out as well and have significantly more stuff in them due to protections and execution modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your solution:

```
mov R1, #45 @x
mov R2, #27 @y

loop:
    cmp R1, R2  @compare R1 with R2
    bne label1  @is R1 not equals to R2? "Branch is Not Equal" to label1, else...

    @<replace with the return R1 statement here>

    label1:
        cmp R1, R2
        bgt sub_xy  @"Branch on Greater Than"
        cmp R1, R2
        blt sub_yx  @"Branch on Lower Than"

    sub_xy:
        sub R1, R1, R2  @R1 = R1 - R2
        b loop  @branch to loop

    sub_yx:
        sub R2, R2, R1  @R2 = R2 - R1
        b loop
```

Came up with this as a newb x86_64 programmer trying to code for ARM for the first time.

EDIT: Corrections/ explanations are in the comments.

Comment: Your `label1` is in a weird place; normally loops run more than once, and it's somewhat more efficient for a branch to fall through than to be taken.  I'd put it at the end, instead of jumping over a `mov r0, r1`;`bx lr` every time ([Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47783926)).  Also, you don't have to re-run `cmp` more than once per iteration; like on x86, conditional-branch instructions only read flags, don't modify them, so you can `cmp` once and `beq out_of_loop`, otherwise fall through to a `bgt`.

Comment: (You don't need 3 branch instructions to sort out the 3 cases, only 2.  Integers are always `<`, `==`, or `>`.  The `else if` part in the C source is redundant).  Also, as an ARM-specific optimization, this looks like a use-case for predicated instructions.  Like `cmp r1, r2` ; `subgt r1,r1, r2` ; `sublt r2,r2, r1`; `bne loop`.  (If "eq" is true, neither of the predicated sub instructions will execute and we fall right out of the loop.  Otherwise we run the next iteration).  Since I didn't use `subs`, `subgt` won't update flags so it's still safe to keep checking the same flags from cmp.